# Implementing Order service in Kafka stream and State Store without RDBMS?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

What I want to do is write an Order service project without using the traditional RDBMS(eg. mysql).After having read the docs from Kafka and confluent for several days, I think Kafka stream and state store could help me to implement this without using RDBMS.

**But how to store the data that has a long list result in state store?Especially when I need to query result like using limit and offset?**

eg:
I have a table, the columns are:

| userId | orderId | ... |

One user may have many order rows to store, so I need a query method to search the key:userId result in the state store with start and limit.But I can't find a method in the Kafka stream State Store interface.

Do I have to do this using an RDBMS? What is the standard method for me to implement an application like this?

Comment: Maybe "Interactive Queries" help? https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: Only key/value store is not what my need, because the value for the key sometimes is a verify big list, how can I put it in the key/value store?Or do you mean using custome state store?

Comment: You can put any type into the value. Thus, if you provide a corresponding class that wraps all your attributes it should work -- no need for a custom state store IMHO. -- You would need a custom store only, if you want to do more complex queries than key lookups and key-ranges.

Comment: Thanks for reply! What I still feel puzzeled is how can I query in mysql like ` where key=? limit 0, 100`. As the result maybe very large, and I have to query by pagination read.Or the state store can give me a Iterable method so I can get the result in iterable read?

Comment: Query capabilities are limited compared to a SQL engine. Kafka Streams supports key lookup queries only. If you do range queries, you get an iterator back. Maybe read the docs? https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html